# How to understand "Implicit Synchronization" for concurrent kernel

Tags: cuda

In Nvida CUDA C Programming Guide 4.0, section 3.2.5.5.4, it says that two commands from different streams cannot run concurrently if a device-to-device memory copy is issued in-between them. I am not sure what it exactly means. Hope someone can clarify my confusion.

Let's say my program have two streams, stream 0 and stream 1. The following is the order kernels are launched to these streams.

Kernel 0.0 (stream 0; assume the execution time is 10 ms)

kernel 1.0 (stream 1; assume the execution time is 1 ms)

kernel 1.1 (stream 1; assume the execution time is 3 ms)

kernel 1.2 (stream 1; this kernel causes a device-to-device memory copy, assume the execution time is 1 ms)

kernel 1.3 (stream 1; assume the execution time is 6 ms)

Let's also assume the program doesn't have other overhead and the GPU has enough SM to run these kernels concurrently. My question is if kernel 0.0 can run concurrently with kernel 1.2 and kernel 1.3? What is the running time for the whole program?

Comment: How can Kernel 1.2 "cause" a device-to-device memory copy? To do that, you need to use a host API call like cudaMemcpy

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That is where I got confused. In my kernel 1.2, I have some instructions that copy some data from some memory location to another memory location. That is what I mean "kernel 1.2 causes a device-to-device memory copy". I guess you will say the kernels in stream 0 and those in stream 1 can run concurrently, right?

Comment: Presumably all of you kernels read and write global memory, otherwise what would you run them? That isn't what a device-to-device memory copy is.

Comment: I see. From my measurement, the time for sequentially running these kernels are pretty much the same as the time for concurrent kernels. Is there any way we can know if kernels are executed concurrently or not? And what might the reasons if concurrent kernels do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, a device-to-device memory copy is done using `cudaMemcpy()` from the host; kernels are free to read and write global memory as they please. Kernels *may* overlap if they are in different streams but there is no guarantee. The exact speedup will depend on the SM utilization by each of the kernels. Nvidia recommends using events to time kernel execution (a start and stop timer) to determine if the overlapping version is faster than the sequential. You can compare this output with either switching kernels to stream 0 or running your app in the profiler, which serializes kernel execution.